# How does R's system.time work?

Tags: r, scope

I have some R code:

```
time.read = system.time(df <- data.frame(fread(f)))
print(class(time.read))
#[1] "proc_time"
print(class(df))
#[1] "data.frame"
```

Somehow when this is executed, in the main R environment/scope:

- time.read has a value
- df exists and contains the correct data.frame

I thought variables created inside a function were not available outside of the function's scope? How does this work? And why after running the following does y not exist in the main R environment?

```
fx <- function(z){return(1)}
out = fx(y <- 300)
print(out)
#[1] 1
print(y)
#Error in print(y) : object 'y' not found
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Great question! R does something peculiar with its argument, which causes a lot
of confusion but is also very useful.

When you pass an argument into a function in R, it doesn’t get evaluated until
it’s actually used inside the function. Before that, the argument just sits
around in a special container called a *[promise](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects)*. Promises hold an
expression and the environment in which they are supposed to be evaluated – for
arguments, that’s the caller’s environment.

But as soon as you *use* the argument inside the function, its value is
computed. This is how `system.time` works. Simplified:

```
system.time = function (expr) {
    before = proc.time()
    expr
    proc.time() - before
}
```

In other words, the function simply records the time before looking at its
argument. *Then* it looks at its argument and thus causes its evaluation, and
then it records the time elapsed. But remember that the evaluation of the
argument happens in the caller’s scope, so in your case the target of the
assignment (`df`) is also visible in the parent scope.

In your second example, your function `fx` never looks at its argument, so it
never gets evaluated. You can easily change that, forcing the evaluation of its
argument, simply by using it:

```
fx <- function(z) {
    z
    return(1)
}
```

In fact, R has a special function – [`force`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/force.html) for this purpose:

```
fx <- function(z) {
    force(z)
    return(1)
}
```

But `force` is simply syntactic sugar, and its definition is simply to return
its argument:

```
force = function (x) x
```

The fact that R doesn’t evaluate its arguments immediate is useful because you
can also retrieve the unevaluated form inside the function. This is known as
*[non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html)*, and it’s sometimes used to evaluate the
expression in a *different* scope (using the [`eval`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html) function with its
argument `envir` specified), or to retrieve information about the unevaluated,
expression.

Many functions use this, most prominently [`plot`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.default.html), which guesses default
axis labels based on the plotted variables/expressions:

```
x = seq(0, 2 * pi, length.out = 100)
plot(x, sin(x))
```

Now the axis labels are `x` and `sin(x)`. The `plot` function knows this because
inside it, it can look at the unevaluated expressions of its function arguments:

```
xlabel = deparse(substitute(x))
ylabel = deparse(substitute(y))
```

[`substitute`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/substitute.html) retrieves the unevaluated expression.
[`deparse`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/deparse.html) converts it into a string representation.

Comment: Good answer, except that `system.time` doesn't actually use `eval` (at least not in my version of R).  It evaluates the promise expression directly, without even using `force`, as in your second version of `fx`.

Comment: @mrip Yeah, I’ve half a mind to rewrite my answer, because my simplification actually makes it *more* complicated. In R, *every* function argument is a promise, and non-standard evaluation is simply a special case of this where the user didn’t evaluate the function argument (immediately), but instead `substitute`d it.

Comment: @mrip Scratch that, I’ve gone ahead and completely rewrote the answer. What do you think? It’s more correct now, but is it still understandable?

Comment: Looks great to me.  Understandable, and accurate.  Better than before IMO.